# Unit testing angular 11 service stub problem

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I'm trying to run unit test of my component.

component.ts:

```
async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
  await this.dataProviderService.getCurrencyCodesList().then(data => {
    this.currencyList = data;
  });
  this.currencyList.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.code > b.code ? 1 : -1;
  });
// ...
}
```

Service method used:

```
async getCurrencyCodesList(): Promise<any[]> {
    // ...
    const currencyCodes = currencyList.map(data => {
      return {code: data.code, currency: data.currency, table: data.table};
    });

    return currencyCodes;
  }
```

In spec.ts file I tried to create a stub

```
//...
it('should have currencies in the list', () => {
    expect(component.currencyList.length).toBeGreaterThan(1);
});
});
class DataProviderServiceStub {
  async getCurrencyCodesList(): Promise<Observable<any[]>> {
    return of ([{code: 'PLN', table: 'A'},
                {code: 'EUR', table: 'A'}]);
  }
}

// then this:
class DataProviderServiceStub {
  async getCurrencyCodesList(): Promise<any[]> {
    return ([{code: 'PLN', table: 'none'},
             {code: 'EUR', table: 'A'}]);
  }
} 
//also tried return (of)([]), ([{}]) etc.
```

The problem is I'm getting such Karma error for using .sort on array I'm getting from stub:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.currencyList.sort is not a function
TypeError: this.currencyList.sort is not a function
```

It sometimes comes out as error, other time as AfterAll error and sometimes it says everything is fine. What am I doing wrong?

Test result failed: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once OnInit is called, this block is executed:
`this.dataProviderService.getCurrencyCodesList()`

Next, `then` block is pushed to a microtask queue and scheduled for a call:

```
.then(data => {
    this.currencyList = data;
  });
```

then it proceeds to `this.currencyList.sort`
Since `then` block is still queued and promise is still not resolved, nothing is assigned to `currencyList`, hence it contains either `undefined` or whatever was assigned to it on initiation. It calls `sort` method on `undefined`. As `undefined` does not have `sort` method, it throws error.

Why are you calling `then` if you are using async/await? This is how it should be implemented the  `async/await` way.

```
async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
  this.currencyList = await this.dataProviderService.getCurrencyCodesList();
  this.currencyList.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.code > b.code ? 1 : -1;
  });
// ...
}
```

It basically waits until `getCurrencyCodesList()` promise has been resolved and writes response to `currencyList` field. Then it proceeds further the regular sync flow.

Since you are using promises, your stubs should return promises as well not observables. In your case, I'd use jasmine spies rather than stubs for testing, example:

```
const localizationProviderSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj<LocalizationProviderService>('LocalizationProviderService', ['getCurrencyCodesList']);
```

Add spy to your provider list, you are most likely using TestBed, and then use it in your test cases like this:

```
it('should have currencies in the list', async () => {
   const expected = [{code: 'PLN', table: 'A'}, {code: 'EUR', table: 'A'}];

   localizationProviderSpy
     .getCurrencyCodesList
     .and
     .returnValue(Promise.resolve(expected));

   await component.ngOnInit();

   expect(component.currencyList.length).toBeGreaterThan(1);
   expect(component.currencyList).toEqual(expected);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Anyways the tests expects being in this ngOnInit.then are like not visible. Even test name says "SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS should have currencies in the list"

Comment: Try using async/await (updated example), another option would be to call ```done``` callback inside ```then``` block

Answer (score 0):

The `getCurrencyCodesList()` method is asynchronous and when you run `this.currencyList.sort`, `this.currencyList` has not yet received the `data` and it is not yet an array and therefore does not have the `sort()` function

What you can do is set the `Array` type to `currencyList`

```
private currencyList: any []
```

Comment: It comes with more problems when changed to private. Also I can't run like expect(component.currencyList.length).toBeGreaterThan(1) - because currencyList is not accesible... also tried curencyList: any[] = [] etc.

Comment: being private is not a necessity, I just put it out of habit. If you call sort () inside .then () it won't give you this error, I just don't know if it will solve your problem

Comment: Oh yeah, that answers the described problem. Unfortunately I still can't run expect(component.currencyList.length).toBeGreaterThan(1); - says it's undefined